# PHP headers are not working in WordPress ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a PHP script that generate and download CSV file. Following is the code of that script:

```
<?php

$cars = array(
  array("Volvo",22,1888),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=csvfile.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Car', 'Year', 'Miles' ));

//Loop through the array and add to the csv
foreach ($cars as $row) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
exit;
?>
```

This script work fine when I access it directly, But my aim is to use this script in a WordPress AJAX call, I have created the AJAX using WordPress AJAX API as following:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_export_timeline', 'export_timeline' );
```

And then same PHP code (that is pasted above) is written in callback function `export_timeline`, but instead of generating CSV and downloading against the AJAX call, printed array is returned in response. There is no error in AJAX in call, I have tested with echoing other string, its responding fine.

But in case of upper mentioned script, I think PHP headers are not working in callback function, because instead of generating and downloading CSV, its echoing the array in response. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Also add `exit;` or `die;` at end of code

Comment: @Sudharshan Nair , Already done. but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge PHP headers do not work with AJAX calls:

what you can do is create csv data in your php code and echo that as a response to your callback.

Your php code must return a json as 
`echo json_encode(['data' => $data, 'status' => 'success' ]);`
`$data` variable must have valid CSV formatted data.

In your javascript you can use the following for CSV download:

```js
function download_csv(){
    var make_download = (function () {
            var $a = $('<a>', {
              'class': 'csv-downloader',
              'style': 'display: none'
            });
            $('body').find('.csv-downloader').remove();
            $('body').append($a);
            return function (data, fileName) {
                const blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"}),
                    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                $a[0].href = url;
                $a[0].download = fileName;
                $a[0].click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
        }());
    $.when($.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      url: URL, // url here
    })).then((response) => {
      if (response.status == 'success') {
        make_download(response.data, `my-file.csv`);
      }      
    })
  }
```

Comment: Before trying this JS, I want to tell you that, js function that is sending the AJAX request is written in js file and included in page, the JS function that is sending AJAX function is not written on same page where the form is existing. Will this script work in this way..??

Comment: if you send you request to correct URL and follow the steps. This code will definately work as this code I have used in some of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to directly call the url, without an ajax call, then it should work.

Comment: I have to pass a post ID through a form from a admin page, so CSV get data against that ID and will be downloaded. As I mentioned that this script work fine when access directly, but my client's requirement is not to submit the form on a blank page where the script will run, He need this to be done with AJAX, I already provided the solution by accessing this script directly, But that is not suitable and required.

Comment: You can't modify Headers via an ajax call. If you submit your form, you should create the data and set the headers. It will not show a blank page, it will just open a download window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify headers as below

```
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=csvfile.csv" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: I tried these headers, But not working. Same result, Instead of generating and downloading the CSV, its returning the printed array in response.